# How to gracefully stop python unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm using the python unittest framework to test external equipment.  In this particular use case I'd actually like to have python do an endurance test that will take a couple of days. (One test will only take a couple minutes but it will be repeated very often.)

In this scenario I'd like to be able to gracefully stop the testing and either resume or restart it later.  I can live with restarting it later, but right now I have no means of a graceful stop.

By graceful stop I envision something like:  Upon pressing `Ctrl-C`, last test is finished and the results are returned.

Is there any built in way to achieve this? If not, how I achieve it otherwise?

Comment: Is there only one `testFoo()` method which is long-running, and could be interrupted?  Or do you need to be able to interrupt any test?

Comment: @delnan, I'm inclined to agree.  But it's also fair to leverage `unittest` for things other than unit tests (as long as you recognize that `unittest` is designed for just those use cases).  For example, you might have to concede that the test just cannot be halted gracefully.  :/

Comment: @delnan, Basically Brian Cain already explained it. The unittest framework is a great *framework* and as such useful in many applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by taking a much closer look at the unittest documentation:
By calling:

```
unittest.installHandler()
```

a signal handler for Ctrl-C is installed and all results that do:

```
unittest.registerResult(result)
```

will gracefully exit in case of a Ctrl-C. Which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the unittest [command-line docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-options).

> **Control-C** during the test run waits for the current test to end
>   and then reports all the results so far. A second control-C raises the
>   normal KeyboardInterrupt exception.

Consequently you could catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception to put the next test into a sleep loop after the results so far have been reported. The sleep loop could then wait for further keypresses to abort the whole test or continue.

Comment: I just add that this (as well as @Martin's) solution is available since python 2.7.