# Closing resources when interrupting a Python unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am using the standard library `unittest` module (so I run my tests with `python -m unittest`).

I have defined `setUpModule` to start a subprocess in the background (with `subprocess.Popen`) and `tearDownModule` to close its input and output streams, then call `os.killpg` on its process ID.

This all works fine if I let a test run its course, but if I stop it early using `Ctrl-C`, I get a bunch of warnings and my terminal slows to a crawl:

```
KeyboardInterrupt
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=6 mode='rb'>
/.../lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py:2150: ImportWarning: sys.meta_path is empty
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.FileIO name=7 mode='wb'>
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name='/dev/null'>
```

Is there some way I can intercept the `KeyboardInterrupt` in order to clean up properly? Is there a better way to start and stop an external program for a test module?

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/13382205/5162063

Comment: That appears to register `KeyboardInterrupt` handlers for test method results, not the module itself. It's not clear since there's not much information there.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your tests are organized, you could also catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` and call the `tearDown` method in the `except` block:

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_one(self):
      for i in range(1<<20):
         if i % 271 == 0:
            print i

  @classmethod
  def tearDownClass(cls):
      print("\nteardown")

if __name__ == '__main__':
     try:
        unittest.main()
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
        MyTestCase.tearDownClass()
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to override the `unittest.TextTestRunner` and catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` in the `run()` method, and then run the module tear down.

```
class CustomTestRunner(unittest.TextTestRunner):
    def _makeResult(self):
        self.my_result = self.resultclass(self.stream, self.descriptions, self.verbosity)
        return self.my_result

    def run(self, test):
        try:
            return super().run(test)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.stream.writeln("Caught KeyboardInterrupt.")
            self.my_result.printErrors()
            test._handleModuleTearDown(self.my_result)  # do cleanup
            return self.my_result
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I tried following the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205386/1475412 and found a solution.

I registered a handler for `SIGINT` that kills the subprocess, then calls `sys.exit()`. I thought I would be able to re-raise `KeyboardInterrupt` inside the handler but that didn't work.